# Switch data from a column to another without swapping the headings

Tags: vba, excel

How do I create an Excel macro to switch the data from a column to another? But I don't want to swap the headings.

Code:

```
Sub myCode()
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim v As Variant
Set r1 = Columns("A:B")
Set r2 = Columns("B:B")
v = r1.Value
r1.Value = r2.Value
r2.Value = v
End Sub
```

My problem is that it swaps the headings too. I just need the data swapped.

Comment: Instead of selecting the entire column, you can select A2:BX where X is an int representing the last row. You can setup X with the xlUp function.

Comment: it should be a automated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the header row

```
Sub dural()
   Dim A2 As Range, B2 As Range
   Set A2 = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)
   Set B2 = Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count)

   v = A2
   A2.Value = B2.Value
   B2 = v
End Sub
```